# highlight filter text in recyclerview using searchview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have created recyclerview with searchview, but I want to highlight the text in recyclerview which I enter in the searchview. I have tried some mehtod in onviewholder but it didn't work. Is there any way to do it? I have share screenshot and code below, please help me to do it.

bookadapter.kt

```
class bookadapter( private var booklist:ArrayList<Booksmodel>, private val itemClickListener: 
OnItemClicklistner):RecyclerView.Adapter<bookadapter.bookholder>() {

val searchText:String?=null


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): bookholder {
    val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.singlebook,parent,false)
    return bookholder(view)
}

fun filterlist(filterlist:ArrayList<Booksmodel>){

    booklist=filterlist

    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: bookholder, position: Int) {
    val view=booklist[position]

    holder.bind(view,itemClickListener)


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return booklist.size
}
inner class bookholder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val bookname:TextView=view.findViewById(R.id.recbooknametxt)
    val bookpublication=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recbookpubtxt)
    val bookdept=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recbookdepttxt)
    val bookimage=view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.recbookimg)

    fun bind(book:Booksmodel,clicklistner:OnItemClicklistner){
        bookname.text=book.BookName
        bookpublication.text=book.BookPublication
        bookdept.text=book.Department
        Picasso.get().load(book.BookImage).into(bookimage)
        itemView.setOnClickListener{
            clicklistner.onItemclick(book)
        }
    }
}

interface OnItemClicklistner{
    fun onItemclick(books:Booksmodel)
}
}
```

books.kt

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragmentmenu, menu)
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)

    val searchView:SearchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {

            filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id=item.itemId
    when (id) {
        R.id.search -> {

            return true
        }
        R.id.sort->{
            Toast.makeText(context,"sort",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}


private fun filter(text: String) {
    val filteredlist = ArrayList<Booksmodel>()

    for (item in booklist) {
        if (item.BookName!!.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(text.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
        ) {
            filteredlist.add(item)
        }
    }
    if (filteredlist.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Data Found..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        bookadapter.filterlist(filteredlist)
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot Highlight Pr in recyclerview item]

Answer (score 1):

Here I create a method you can use it either in your Activity class or in your Adapter class just pass your `textView`, `originalText`, `searchText` in the method/ function as argument

```
private fun setSpannableText(
    textView: TextView,
    originalText: String,
    searchText: String
) {
    var index: Int = originalText.lowercase().indexOf(searchText.lowercase())
    val spannableString = SpannableString(originalText)
    while (index >= 0) {
        val endIndex: Int = index + searchText.length
        val fcs = ForegroundColorSpan(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                mContext,
                R.color.yourHighlightColor
            )
        )
        spannableString.setSpan(
            fcs,
            index,
            endIndex,
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
        )

        // Find the next occurrence of the search text
        index = originalText.lowercase().indexOf(searchText.lowercase(), endIndex)
    }
    textView.text = spannableString
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If coloring the searched text with different color is enough highlighting for you, try following:

Modify your `bookadapter` class:

```
class bookadapter() : ... {
    var searchText: String = ""
    ...

    // update your adapter about the current search text as well
    fun filterList(filterList: List<BookModel>, searchText: String) {
        this.searchText = searchText
        booklist = filterList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Then, modify your `bookholder` to highlight part of the text that matches `searchText`:

```
inner class bookholder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val bookNameTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_book_name)

    fun bind(book: BookModel, clickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        if (searchText.isNotBlank()) {
            val highlightedText = book.bookName.replace(searchText, "<font color='red'>$searchText</font>", true)
            bookNameTextView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(highlightedText, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            bookNameTextView.text = book.bookName
        }
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClick(book)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in your activity/fragment's `private fun filter(text: String)` function, you need to pass the filtered text to the adapter:

```
bookadapter.filterlist(filteredlist, text)
```

I made a working demo reflecting your use case (simplified), check out the [demo](https://github.com/phamtdat/FilterHighlightDemo) if you are still unsure. The result looks like follow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQNRp.jpg

Comment: Glad to help. In that case please accept my answer. If you don't know how, please refer to stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers